# How to allow for short-selling (rolling efficient frontier) in matlab?

Tags: matlab, finance, portfolio

I have a 183x12 where the first column represents the monthly dates and the other 11 columns are the assets.

I try to use the rolling efficient frontier function from the Matlab documentation:

https://nl.mathworks.com/help/finance/frontier.html

By using this line of code:

```
[PortWts,AllMean,AllCovariance] = frontier(Universe,Window,Offset,NumPorts,ActiveMap)
```

Where:

```
Window = 12
Offset = 12
NumPorts = 11
ActiveMap = 183x11 matrix of ones
```

However, I would like to add Conset to the line of code where I allow for short selling, as the default is that short selling is disallowed.

My question is, how can I add that?

https://nl.mathworks.com/help/finance/portcons.html

Answer (score 0):

The constraint is pretty easy to achieve, just call the [portcons function](https://mathworks.com/help/finance/portcons.html) as follows:

```
ConSet = portcons('PortValue',1,11,'AssetLims',-1,AssetMax,11);
```

where `AssetMax` is either a scalar or a vector defining the upper boundaries of the asset weights. From the official documentation:

> **AssetLims**
>
> Minimum and maximum allocation per asset.
>
> *AssetMin (required)* Scalar or vector of length NASSETS, specifying
>   minimum allocation per asset.
>
> *AssetMax (required)* Scalar or vector of length NASSETS, specifying
>   maximum allocation per asset.
>
> *NumAssets (optional)* See [pcalims](https://mathworks.com/help/finance/pcalims.html).

Comment: I did use the below stated code, but that did not work..

ConSet = portcons('AssetLims', AssetMin, AssetMax, NumAssets);

Comment: Well, your code doesn't look like mine, at all. Did you see an error? If not, what is the wrong result you get?